# How to make a repetive procedure with LinearModelFit

Tags: list-manipulation

I start with a list of lists:

```
d1={{{0, 10}, {1, 20}, {2, 30}, {3, 40}, {4, 50}, {5, 60}, {6, 70}, {7, 
   80}, {8, 90}}, {{0, 10}, {1, 20}, {2, 30}, {3, 40}, {4, 50}, {5, 
   60}, {6, 70}, {7, 80}}, {{0, 10}, {1, 20}, {2, 30}, {3, 40}, {4, 
   50}, {5, 60}, {6, 70}}, {{0, 10}, {1, 20}, {2, 30}, {3, 40}, {4, 
   50}, {5, 60}}, {{0, 10}, {1, 20}, {2, 30}, {3, 40}, {4, 50}}};
```

I would like to apply a LinearModelFit on each list, but as a repetive process, i.e., something looking like:

```
Do[LinearModelFit[d1[[i]], x, x] // Normal, {i, 5}]
```

Can someone help (mathematica 10)?
Thank you all in advance for your time.

PS: The command

```
LinearModelFit[d1[[1]], x, x, ConfidenceLevel -> .99] // Normal
```

works perfectly but I would like something more automated.

Comment: Take a look at `Map`: `(LinearModelFit[#, x, x, ConfidenceLevel -> .99] // Normal) & /@ d1`

Comment: Voting to close as "easily found in the docs". Probably also a duplicate of the [common pitfalls thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/131), but glad you got help in any case. Welcome, BTW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Table` and `Length@d1` as iteration limit

```
Normal@Table[LinearModelFit[d1[[i]], x, x, ConfidenceLevel -> .99], {i, Length@d1}]
```

[image]

Or, even shorter

```
Normal@Map[LinearModelFit[#, x, x, ConfidenceLevel -> .99] &, d1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and your response!